# Can i used these aliases in some sort of config file?

Tags: docker, alias, ssh-config

#### I have many of these kinds of aliases, the part before = is the host in ssh config

```
alias sshConfigHost='ssh -t hostname docker exec -it containerName bash'
```

Could I add these to some sort of config file? The hostname is defined in ssh config so it's being used twice in a way, could I have a place holder like `%<whatever>` that it  would take the hostname from ssh config.

If not then could I at least have the container name in my ssh config, then pull it into the cmd using a placeholder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to use your alias without any trailing "arguments" (i.e. in a shell you want to call sole `sshConfigHost`, not something like `sshConfigHost -c "shell code here"`).

If so, you can put everything in your `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host friendlyName
   RequestTTY yes
   Hostname hostname
   RemoteCommand docker exec -it containerName bash
```

(In case there is `Host *` or so, keep in mind that [for each parameter, the first obtained value will be used](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/116025/108618).)

Now you just do:

```
ssh friendlyName
```

and `ssh` will act as if you did:

```
ssh -t hostname 'docker exec -it containerName bash'
```

Define as many `Host …` sections as you wish. Some of them may use the same `Hostname` and different `RemoteCommand`, or whatever. The point is you *can* build a rich config, so in a shell it's enough to `ssh oneword` and the config will fill in *everything* for you, depending on `oneword`.

The config file is deliberately so powerful, it can specify every option. See `man 5 ssh_config`. I felt intimidated by this concept (why bother with some "obscure" config while I can specify options and such in the command line like with any other tool?) until I discovered it's neat and convenient. It is the Right Way to use `ssh`. In general if there is anything you would need to repeat again and again when calling `ssh`, consider putting it in the config file.

And then there is no need for accompanying aliases in the shell. The whole config is in your `~/.ssh/config`.

Comment: perfect this is exactly what I wanted, I didn't want to use those aliases I thought that I would be confined to them and the best case scenario would be to get some stuff from ssh config, thanks a lot.